# HTML error. Tag not closed

Tags: javascript, html

Lets imagine this scenario:
In your web site you allow your user to post html (Of course you have to be aware to security issues). Your user posts:

`<div> Main div <div> child div </div>`.

Forgetting to close the Main div.
When I serve the page containing the post with the bad html, I would be delivering a page that is all messed up.

Is there some way or an html tag to "encapsulate" or to isolate a portion of html in a page and let the user be responsible for his own ad? The idea is to implement an advertise system where the user is allowed to design his own ads.

This could also be useful to isolate errors when designing my own pages.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You say "be aware to security issues" - and I actually think any framework that handles the security issues will also handle this mismatched tag.  After all, mismatched-tags (or unclosed tags, etc) could be used as part of an attack, so protecting against one will trivially guard against the other.

Comment: @cloudfeet How are mismatched tags going to be a security problem?

Comment: Could perfectly be an atack. Could close some tag your page originally opens and make your page look horrible. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: By the way. Just developing http://cometside.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there some way or an html tag to "encapsulate" or to isolate a portion of html in a page and let the user be responsible for his own ad?

You can use an [`iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) to do that.

Or: Browsers are very tolerant of broken HTML, you could use the browser to clean it up.

For example:

```
var str = "<div>This is broken HTML<div>missing end tags";
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = str; // Parse it
str = e.innerHTML; // Serialize it properly
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/omuxocu/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/omuxocu/1/edit)

When I run that with the string `<div>This is broken HTML<div>missing end tags`, I get back:

```
<div>This is broken HTML<div>missing end tags</div></div>
```

Some browsers may make the tags all caps.

Alternately, use a server-side solution like JSoup (with which you could also sanitize the input; very useful!). You haven't mentioned a server-side language; JSoup is compatible with any of the JVM-based languages, and I expect by now there are translations to other platforms...

Comment: Testing your solution.

Comment: Dear T.J.: Your solution has proved to be a good one. Insetead of delivering HTML, Delivering a <div id="ad"></div><script>vFill the div with id="ad" as you showed</script>. As I said. Just want to make the advertiser responsible of how it looks. "Try your ad in as many browser as you want i am just responsible to impress it". Blocking tags or witelisting them is something I can achieve with a good java code or some server side solutions proposed in other answers. Thank you very much. You helped a lot.

Comment: @mdev: *"...something I can achieve with a good java code or some server side solutions..."* I assume you mean *JavaScript*, not Java, if you're talking client-side (*"java **or** server side..."*). :-)

Answer (score 0):

If using online editors like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) is an option for your project, they contain HTML validation features that will 'fix up' HTML entered by users (as best they can) or allow you to prevent users from entering certain HTML tags altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much. As i said in another answer. The idea is to make the user responsible for his ad. As far as I know he/her could use dreamweaber or notepad to design the ad.

Answer (score 0):

I use CKEditor in one of my projects.

I don't think normal users will waste their time dealing with coding proper HTML. Most of them don't even know HTML.

In my observations from one classifieds site I operate, users just cut and paste their ads from other site the ad was already posted to. If the content is cut and paste from an HTML page, using CKEditor, it just appears exactly as it is.

Comment: I will put an eye on CKEditor: You are more than probably right about designers dealing with HTML. Beyond that. User could make some mistake copying and still leave some tag open. Or even exposed to some sort of atack (Like closing some div that contains the ad). Thank you very much

Comment: Users do not copy and paste the html code, but instead, they usually copy from an HTML page. When it's pasted in CKEditor, it knows the proper html format, including the html tags and css styling.